# Full URI for http request to retrieve Podio item

Tags: javascript, jquery, podio

So I am new to Podio and after I have figured how to authenticate, I am trying to make my first API call.

I succeeded in authenticating as follows:

```
https://podio.com/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&refresh_token=<refresh_token>
```

I went to `https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360` to test retrieveing an item, and I was able to retrieve correctly my item.

Now given my item 445614135 and that you retrieve an item by the call `/item/445614135` what precede this in the URL? In other words what would be the full URI if I want to do  call from JQuery?

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

According to the answer below using the **app_token**, I tried the POST request suggested, but I got back the following:

```
{
  "error_parameters": {},
  "error_detail": null,
  "error_propagate": false,
  "request": {
    "url": "http://api.podio.com/item/445614135/",
    "query_string": "oauth_token=***",
    "method": "POST"
  },
  "error_description": "No matching operation could be found. The path '/item/445614135/' was not found..",
  "error": "not_found"
}
```

Obviously I blinded the app_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the item details by requesting to this URL,

```
https://api.podio.com/item/445614135/?oauth_token=your_auth_token
```

Comment: Is the oauth_token the app_token? And is it with a POST?

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Making clear that it is a GET, and that the "oauth_token" you refer to is the "access token" generated with registering the app.

Comment: @mzereba Glad to know that you've resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. The URL "https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-22360", shows getItem method is not POST, its GET method.
2. Are you using JS sdk client library?
3. If you are using client library, you can call getItem method from ItemAPI